# How can I view the whole model? There seems to be a "shadow" that shows only shows portion fo the model

Tags: modeling, camera

[image]

I am trying to view a .stl model, but when I zoom out, there seems to be a some sort of a "shadow" that only goes about certain distance from the camera. Is there a way to remove this "shadow"?

Answer (score 2):

this is your clipping distance, id imagine that when you imported it the scale has been multiplied by some factor. due to the fact clipping is set by default to 1000m, i doubt you need an .stl this big. fix by scaling down or navigate to the little left arrow next to your gizmo, go to view and increase the clipping end to what ever is needed.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that the concept is called the "clipping distance", so I will do better next time when doing some search on my own. I have scaled down the model and it worked! thank you :)